# Which pages should be present in the sitemap

Tags: seo, wordpress, sitemap

So if I have a WordPress blog for example, then out of the following which should be present in the sitemap and which should not be?

1. posts - these will be obviously.
2. pages - should be.
3. categories - ?
4. date archives - ?
5. tags - ?

What kind of SEO impact does it have to list all tags, categories and archives pages in the sitemap or not list them at all and give them a meta robot `noindex`.

Answer (score 2):

All you need are posts and pages in the sitemap file to give Google a pathway to your entire site's content.

You should only include category and tag archives if your site is reasonably active which will guarantee that the content there will rotate frequently enough to not be considered duplicate.  If you are not an active site (defined as daily or near daily updates) then I would not include archive pages.  If you do choose to include them, make sure they are set to show excerpts and not complete posts to help avoid duplicate content penalties.

Comment: yeah, i am showing only excerpts on the tag/categories/archive/home pages. and the site is active with posts coming up every week or so

Comment: As long as you are showing exceprts, the frequency is less important as the content should look different enough from the actual posts. If you really want to be sure, write custom excerpts too.

Answer (score 0):

Posts and pages are the most important webpages to include in the sitemap for WordPress website. Including categories and tags depends on the blog that you have.